# Managing Resources with FRP in Scala RX

Tags: scala, frp

I'm using `scala rx` for an application. I have a reactive variable holding a `File` (which is a PDF file). I'm using a library to render pages from this pdf file to the screen. Now the PDF library I'm using gives me an object (let's call it `Doc`), which I can use to render single pages. But in order to render a page from a `Doc` object, the `Doc` object must be opened (thus the resource must be acquired).

Right now I'm loading the pdf file for each page I'm rendering anew (creating a new `Doc` object and closing it after rendering the single page). This makes the rendering of the page functional (given a file and a page number, return an image).

Is there a way to cling to an opened resource **and close it on change** in FRP in general, and for `scala rx` in particular? How would one handle this very common situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply enclose the Doc object.  So instead of render being

```
def render(file: File, pageNumber: Int): Image =  // blah blah blah
```

change it to:

```
def open(file: File): (Int => Image) = {
  val doc = // call your library to read file
  (x: Int) => doc.getPage(x)
}
```

and then pass the function open returns to whatever page change signal you're reacting to.

**Edit**:  Oh, I see, so you're saying you want it to close the file whenever the file:File signal changes to be a different file.  In that case you should be able do something like this:

```
def pageGetterRx(file: Rx[File]): Rx[Int => Image] = {
  val doc: Var[Doc] = Var(null)
  val o = file.foreach { f =>
    Option(doc()).foreach(_.close)
    doc() = PdfLib.read(f)  // or however you do the reading
  }
  Rx {
    (x: Int) => doc().getPage(x)
  }
}
```

**Edit 2**: To clarify, if you impose a "assemble network of functions phase / run the network on some signal(s) phase" distinction on FRP, the above function would be called only once; in the assemble phase.  To say it another way, `pageGetterRx` (a lousy name, I'm fully aware) doesn't participate in a FR way, instead it returns a signal of lambdas that each close over one particular file and return pages from it.

Comment: And how do I make sure `doc` gets closed when it's no longer used?

Comment: Hand wave about the garbage collector.  ;-)  I mean, there's no other way to do it unless you have some other signal that tells you when it's no longer used, in which case you can just make open return two functions, one for each signal.

Comment: The question is specifically about how to free the resource in a defined way. I'm sorry if this was not apparent (I added an emphasis).

Comment: If you can argue that this is not possible, this would also be a valid answer.

Comment: Sorry if this isn't idiomatic, I've never used scala rx, my FRP experience is with Elm.  But it should get the idea of how to do it across... hopefully?

Comment: I think `o` will get GC'ed, but this can be fixed. This solution basically uses side-effects. I think one could use an ordinary variable instead of `doc`, since using FRP locally does not seem to buy you anything here.

Comment: I was kinda wondering that about `o`, it seemed weird to name it at all, but that's what they did in the scala rx intro guide so I stuck with it.  Closing a file is a side effect, so using an observer is the right way to do it.  The thing you get from using FRP locally is a signal to let later reactive functions know when the page-getting lambda has changed.